# iOS: ScrollView doesn't scroll after subviews are added

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am loading an image from the web and some html below it into a UIScrollView. This sits inside a navigationController inside a tabbarcontroller. When I load the subviews the scrollview won't scroll. What am I missing?

Here's the viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[self exhibit] image]];

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width < 600 ) {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(300.0, 140.6);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
}

CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,
                               ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - [[self navigationController] navigationBar].bounds.size.height - [[[self tabBarController] tabBar] bounds].size.height));
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(viewFrame));

UIScrollView *sv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
[sv setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self setView:sv];

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,image.size.width,image.size.height);
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[iv setImage:image];
[iv setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[iv setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[iv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[sv addSubview:iv];
[self setImageView:iv];

NSDictionary *nameMap = @{@"imageView" : [self imageView]};

NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[imageView]-10-|"
                                                                         options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:nameMap];
[sv addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];

NSArray *verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[imageView]"
                                                                         options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:nameMap];
[sv addConstraints:verticalConstraints];

UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 150.0, 300.0, 600.0)];
[wv loadHTMLString:[[self exhibit] text] baseURL:nil];
[sv addSubview:wv];
[self setExhibitText:wv];


}
```

## UPDATE

I've added the following lines, and there's still no change. I can't scroll at all.

```
[sv setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0, 750.0)];
[[wv scrollView] setScrollEnabled:NO];
[[wv scrollView] setBounces:NO];
[wv setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be setting a `contentSize` for your scroll view - without a content size, the scroll view won't know how far you want it to scroll. By default, `UIScrollView` has a zero value content size, so it needs to be set.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView needs both a contenSize and the frame set to a non-zero size. By default:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGRectZero;
```

In your case, the content size should be a CGRect equivalent to imageView and webView combined together.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that you should fix with your code. Firstly, you are downloading the image from the internet synchronously on the main thread. You should never load data from the internet on the main thread.

Another problem that you are having is that a UIWebView is not really intended to be embedded in a UIScrollView. Since a UIWebView has a scrollview of its own, the webview will block all touches to the UIScrollView. If the web view has static content, you can do `webview.setUserInteractionEnabled = NO`

Comment: and as these other guys have said, you need to set the content size

Comment: I had intended to grab the image and cache it when the app loads, but I am doing it this way initially just because it was quick and easy to get the layout going. That said, if I'm not going to use webview is there a better way to render and html string? The text content is coming from an online managed cms that saves the text as html for formatting.

Comment: I'm beginning to think my solution is to get rid of the scrollview all together. Use the whole thing as a webview. Then I can cache the image and text and load it all into the webview together.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not sure if there are other/better ways to render html. I recently had a problem like this and basically, I made a custom webview that had native headers and footers so I essentially had a webview embeded in a scrollview. The header view and footer view do not zoom, but scroll with the webview. I essentially added other views to my webview's scrollview.